# Is talking before noten hatorah a hefsek?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, torah-service, hefsek-interruption

In my shul, after an oleh finishes, he says "emet torateinu hakedosha" and then says the beracha of noten hatorah.
Is this a hefsek?

Looking for sephardic answers please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef* in [סימן קלט - סדר הקריאה והברכות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_8.html#HtmpReportNum0006_L2) where he says:

> **יד:** מנהגינו פשוט שהמברך ברכה אחרונה אחר קריאת התורה, אינו עונה אמן אחר ברכתו, אף על פי שכל העונה אמן אחר ברכותיו הרי זה משובח, הכא שאני, שהרי **מעיקר הדין מותר להפסיק בדברי תורה קודם שבירך ברכה אחרונה**. [ילקוט יוסף, הלכות קריאת התורה עמוד צב]. ‏

"From a strict Halachic POV, one may interrupt with *Divrei Torah* before making the Final Bracha [of Noten HaTorah]."

Since "emet torateinu hakedosha" seems to qualify as *Divrei Torah*, it would not qualify as a Hefsek - an interruption - between the Torah reading and the Bracha.

Comment: Is the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef online ? please provide a link.

Comment: @eramm - I was using a downloaded version of http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/index.html?downloads but now I see they are online - so I added a link. their main online page is http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/d_root__040_hlch.html

Comment: Yagdil Torah VeYadir !