Minhag to say ”emet toratenu hakedosha” before torah blessing
Ive heard people at my shul saying the words “emet toratenu hakedosha” before saying the bracha after the torah reading.

What is the source for this minhag?
Would this pose a halachic issue, as it is an interuption between the torah reading and the bracha?


Just a data point, this minhag is particularly prevalent among Tunisian communities

Who says these words and at what point specifically?

@Dude they're said by the Oleh le Torah after the aliyah is read but before he says the after-bracha

It would seem to be the Notarikon to the second word in the first posuk in the  blessing which follows reading the Torah, namely ( א״מת ת״ורתנו ה״קדושה) is the Notarikon of (ברוך א״תה). And this same posuk then concludes with: (אשר נתן לנו תורת אמת כו׳). In other words, it is making a "Chazaka" on Torat Emet.

See shiur and sources here: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/908722/Keriat-HaTorah-DeclarationsHashem-Imachem!-Emet-Toratenu-HaKedoshah,-&-Goaleinu

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44979/is-talking-before-noten-hatorah-a-hefsek

This minhag is discussed in Kuntres Hefseikim, in which it is quoted on https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=22229 as saying:

הנוהגים להוסיף "אמת תורתנו הקדושה" לפני ברכה אחרונה ימשיכו במנהגם. ומנהג ישראל תורה הוא. ואין חשש הפסק בזה.
וכן בברכות ההפטרה המוסיפים גואלנו, והוא מנהג רוב קהילות הספרדים, וימשיכו במנהגם ואין חשש של הפסק.
כתב השו"ע (סימן קמ, סעיף ב): העומד לקרות בתורה וברך ברכה שלפניה וקרא מקצת פסוקים ודיבר דברי תורה או דברי חול, לא הוי הפסק ואינו צריך לחזור ולברך. ע"כ.
ובבית יוסף (בבדק הבית) כתב וז"ל: ול"נ דברי רבינו אפרים שכיון שהתחיל בדבר שבירך לעלייתו, לא הוי שיחה, הפסק, מידי דהוה אברכת הסעודה. עכ"ל. והרי בברכת הסעודה מותר לדבר אפילו לכתחילה. ועיקר הטעם, שהרי ברכה אחרונה של קריאת התורה היא מתחילה בברוך. ועיין בחידושי הריטב"א (מגילה כא:).
וא"כ מאחר והבית יוסף כתב בשם רבינו אפרים, שקריאת התורה דומה להא דפ"ב דברכות (דף יג) שבפרקים שואל מפני הכבוד וכו', אלמא אע"ג דסח א"צ לחזור ולברך ברכות שלפני ק"ש, ומתחיל ממקום שפסק וק"ש ג"כ היא תורה וכתיב בה תמימה וכו'. ואם מותר לשאול מפני הכבוד, ק"ו שיהא מותר להוסיף ולומר "אמת תורתנו הקדושה" שהוא כבודה של תורה.
ויש שהעירו, וכי צריכים אנו שיאמת את דברי התורה. והרי הם אמתיים וקיימים כשלעצמם. אמנם אין זו טענה שהרי גם בברכה אמרינן "תורת אמת".
ויש שהעירו, כיון שיש אחרים שאינם מוסיפים זאת, והוא יוסיף יראה כגריעותא של האחרים, וגם זו אינה טענה, שהרי בין כך מברכים ברכה אחרונה, ואין חשש של גריעותא, אלא רק מעליותא למי שמוסיף.
ובפסוק "גואלנו" וגו', שהוא פסוק, בזה פשוט שאפשר להוסיף, כפי שנוהגים להוסיף פסוק ראשון ואחרון מהפטרה אחרת, ואין בזה חשש. וא"כ אתי שפיר הנוהגים כן, ואין להם לשנות ממנהגם.
וכבר כתבנו בזה בס' אוצר פסקי הסידור (עמ' קמז) ובס' אהלי שם על הש"ע (א"ח סימן קמ). ועי' בס' נתיבי אור למהר"נ יגן ז"ל (עמוד תצב) שא' חזר בתשובה בגלל זה.
ולפי מה שביארנו שבכל נוסח קבוע אין בו משום הפסק, א"כ אין בדברים כל חשש.
ובזה גם יבואר מה שיש נהגו שהעולה אומר 'חזק חזק ונתחזק' בסוף כל חומש לפני ברכה אחרונה. והובא המנהג בהוספות שבסוף ש"ע הגר"ז ובשו"ת משנה הלכות (ח"ז סימן כב). וכתב בס' אורחות רבינו (ח"ב עמוד שיג) שכן נהג הקהילות יעקב. ובלוח ההלכות והמנהגים כתב שכן נהג הגרז"ר בנגיס. ובספר אשי ישראל (פרק לח הערה מט) בשם ספר זר התורה פקפק בזה משום הפסק. וכן העיר בלוח א"י להגרי"מ טיקוצ'ינסקי (פרשת ויחי). ובלוח דינים ומנהגים אהבת שלום (שנת תשע"ז עמוד תעב בסופו) כתב שהספרדים לא נהגו כן. ע"ש. ועי' בשו"ת שבט הלוי (ח"ז ס"ס רב) ובשו"ת רבבות אפרים (ח"ב סימן צח וח"ד סימן פ). ולהנ"ל מבואר שכל נוסח קבוע אין בו משום הפסק (מלבד מש"כ בבדק הבית וכנ"ל). וכ"כ בס' שומר אמת (ס"פ ויחי) בשם הגר"ח קניבסקי שליט"א, דכיון שהוא מנהג, אין בו משום הפסק.

I may (at some point) translate this and go through the various marei mekomos brought.
Additionally, at this link https://harav.org/books/mahamar_mordechay_shabat_30/#_ftn38, it says that Rav Sholom Messas had this minhag.
Rav Yitzchak Yosef addresses your second question in Yalkut Yosef Hilchos Kriyas Seifer Toro 145:5, as follows:

הנוהגים לומר "אמת תורתינו הקדושה" בסוף קריאת התורה, לפני שיברכו ברכה אחרונה, אין למחות בידם משום הפסק, שיש להם על מה שיסמוכו, שהרי אין ההפסק אלא לאחר שכבר התחיל במצות הקריאה. ומכל מקום טוב ונכון ליעצם בנחת שלא לאומרו.


Those who are accustomed to say "Our holy Torah is true" at the end of the reading of the Torah, prior to saying the after blessing, should not be prevented [from keeping their custom] [by those who think there is a problem] because of interruption, because they have something upon which to rely, since the interruption is only after he was already begun the mitzvah of reading. Nevertheless it is good and correct to advise them softly not to say it.


Have you found an actual source discussing where this minhag came from? Why people say it?

@AvishaiTebeka No
